# How can I sort multiple arrays in PHP with values being dependent on each other to be in the same position?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, math, distribution

I'm trying to create these array maps of values, but I need them to be sorted in a way were different values are dependent on each other being in the same position. You could view them as distribution maps but within each map they "belong" to other values in other arrays. There is a master array which holds the relations between values.

All arrays are 100% identical in length. It's almost like "a table" where each row is the individual array.

These are the arrays I have (pseudo):

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = [6,7,8,9,10];
$array3 = [11,12,13,14,15];
```

And this is my master list of dependencies (basically how they depend on each other):

```
$sort = [[1,7,13],[2,6,11],[1,8,15]];
```

As you can see not all values are present. It's only the values being dependent on each other that are present. How can I now achieve my outcome which is theory would be something like this:

```
$array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
$array2 = [7,6,8,9,10];
$array3 = [13,11,15,12,14];
```

Notice how "8" and "15" doesn't really have anything more to map against so they are just left as combined at the end of their own array. This isn't super important, they could be randomized to just keep the first keys of the array intact for as long as it's possible to create the sorting as intended.

Comment: What if there was `[4,7,14]` at the end of `$sort` array? Would you want the order to be `[2,6,11], [1,8,15], [4,7,14]` then? This means ignoring the first one for maximizing the length. Is that what you meant?

Comment: That's a good question and totally valid - the maximum number of potential "sorted" combinations is preferred. It's not a deal-breaker but yeah, maximizing potential combinations would be ideal.

Comment: I don't think it makes too much sense to try any actual _sorting_ here, but rather create a new result array. I would do something like this: https://3v4l.org/PDXY2 I grouped your three individual arrays into one here (couldn't be bothered to deal with variable variables here, on top of everything else) - and this will "destroy" that original array, so if you still need the original data afterwards, make a copy.

Comment: That's an interesting take @CBroe. I guess you always need to make sure you have one sorting key [] for every array you want to distribute amongst? There's no real issue in creating new arrays. So you are searching for matching keys and add them to their own array and then merge them back into their original array at the beginning. That's really clever. Do you see any downside to this?

Comment: The reason I decided to fill a new array, is that `array_search` doesn't support any "offset." So when the `1` in the first array has already been "found" and moved to the front based on the first entry of $sort (it was already at the front, but lets assume it was moved there) - then we don't need to find _that_ one again, when the `1` in the _third_ entry of $sort gets processed. We'd need to start looking from the 3rd position in the array. But by actually splicing the found numbers out of the array, we can keep on looking with `array_search` then.

Comment: How about is there are multiple values with the same key? Basically if the first array had "1" let's say 5 times. It would just grab the first one it finds, right?